# Internally rewrite URLs in JSF with pretty-confg

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

When I use following code

```
<rewrite match="/foo/(\w+)/" substitute="/bar/$1/" />
```

From following resource [prettyfaces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.0/en-US/html/inbound_rewriting.html)
It makes a redirect, I mean it changes URL in browser from '/foo' to '/bar'.

I want JSF to rewrite URL internally, I mean when user calls '/foo' or '/bar' it has to execute same resource.

Well I know I can add multiple URL pattern for same page bean, but actually URLs are complex (not just foo/bar) and I need to manipulate/rearrange path parameter to point to old URL from new URL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys found the answer.

I had to add attribute `redirect="chain"` to `rewrite` element and it worked.
I hope it will help googlers..

Comment: care to give a more detailed example, so others can more easily learn?

Comment: You might also consider using Rewrite, it's designed to make this much easier: http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/docs/configuration/mapping